# Print large data to file with special format from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev

I need to print some data to a txt file from Python 3.4/3.2.

Each line in the file has this format:

```
   col1  |      col2          |    col3                  | 
   id1      CT_TYPE  value1    CT_TYPE  value2  
   AR     CT1          239        CT2  9.66
   AR     CT3          8.65
   NY     CT1          6.25       CT2  67.89
   NY     CT3         78.61
```

For same id1, if there are more than 2 values of CT_TYPE, they must be printed in both of col2 and col3 and the only the last value of the id1 type can leave col3 empty. For example,  the following print format is wrong.

```
   col1  |      col2          |    col3                  | 
   id1      CT_TYPE  value1     CT_TYPE  value2  
   AR       CT1     239         " this cannot be left as blank"
   AR      CT2  9.66             CT3          8.65
```

For different id1 value, a new line must be added. Fror example, id1 = NY can not be at the same line with AR:

```
  AR     CT3    8.65      NY     CT1   6.25   // this is not allowed.
```

There hundreds of thousands of data lines that need to be printed. I do not want to use sorting because the data size is to large to be kept in a data structure in python. So, I have to load the data from database block by block and print them to file.   I can make sure that each block loaded from database has the same id1 value.

My question is how to make sure that the above format is kept when data is printed block by block ?
In python, I used:

```
   with open(fileName, 'a') as f:
         f.wite(aLine + "\n");
```

How to change the current print position so that the CT_type values of the same id1 type are printed at the same row even enough a newline "\n" has been added after the last data line was printed. For example,  if my file has these:

```
   col1  |      col2         |    col3                  | 
   id1      CT_TYPE  value1    CT_TYPE  value2  
   AR       CT1       239
```

A new data line in a new block is like:

```
    AR     CT2  9.66
```

I want  :

```
  col1  |      col2         |    col3                  | 
   id1      CT_TYPE  value1    CT_TYPE  value2  
   AR       CT1       239       CT2  9.66
```

Not :

```
   col1  |      col2        |    col3                  | 
   id1     CT_TYPE  value1    CT_TYPE  value2  
   AR      CT1         239             
   AR      CT2        9.66
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, I would use something where it only stores the id and cttype until it finds a match on id, then output to file and del from memory. The below is to illust

```
fobj_in = open('file','r')
fobj_out = open('output','a')
unmatched = {}
for line in fobj_in:
    elem = line.split('\t')
    id1, cttype = elem
    if id1 not in unmatched:
        unmatched[id1] = cttype
    else:
        cttype_ = unmatched.pop(id1)
        fobj.write('\t'.join([id1,cttype_, cttype]))
for id in unmatched:
    fobj.write('\t'.join([id, unmatched.pop(id)]))
fobj_in.close()
fobj_out.close()
```

The above is for illustration only, and may have errors or other issues.